# 1 section and 2 cells but 4 indexPath.row

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift4

Swift 4.
I want to return two cells in one section, so in my class `CollectionViewController` I do :

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1 } 

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2 }
```

I see two cells but if I print indexPath.row in the code below (still in the same class), I see `0 1 0 1`. Why is it not only one `0 1`as I have only two cells in one section ?

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    print(indexPath.row)
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: its just two cell, but `cellForItemAt` method called 2 times

Comment: Do you call `reloadData` twice?

Comment: try printing `print("\(index.section) + \(index.row)")`, It will let you know that there is only section 0, which is reloading twice

Comment: I call `````reloadData````` through ````DispatchQueue.main.async {self.collectionView?.reloadData()}```` so i thought there was only one "call" to the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForItemAt` is getting called four times.  Your `numberOfItemsInSection` is hard-coded for 2.  When the view loads `cellForItemAt` is called twice (once for each cell).  It is then getting called twice again when you call `reloadData()` from your `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure.

**Updated - How to avoid the first call:**

You need to store your cell data in an array, and only populate the array just before you call `reloadData()`.  Thus, the array will be empty when the view is first loaded.

```
var yourArray = [YourObject]() //Empty Array    

//..

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //append your two items to the yourArray
    yourArray.append(/*cell1data*/)
    yourArray.append(/*cell2data*/)
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}

//..

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return yourArray.count
}
```

Comment: Got it ! Is it possible to avoid the first call ?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Not sure, because yourArray.count will also return 2 ? what do i do in the second override of the collectionView func ?

Comment: yourArray.count will return 0 when the view loads because the array is empty.  It will only return 2 once you have appended the items to it, before you call `reloadData()`

Comment: oh, smart. Thanks !